# Better way to retrieve data from multiple table using Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-optimization, scaling

I have created quiz app in which i offers quizzes to users and quiz have multiple questions

my tables for question are given

```
1.Question Table
2.QuestionOption Table
3.QuestionImage Table
4.QuestionSolutionImage Table
```

The Question Table is linked with all below tables with foreignKey QuestionId

now for getting questionData i execute this code

```
       $builder = Question::where('TestId', $_testId);
        
       $data = $builder->with(['questionOptions' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('Status',1)
            ->select(['QuestionId', 'id', 'optionText', 'rank', 'isAnswer', 'timeStamp']);
        }]) ->with(['questionImages' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('Status',1)
            ->select(['QuestionId', 'id', 'imagePath', 'thumbPath', 'rank', 'timeStamp']);
        }])->with(['solutionImages' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('Status',1)
            ->select(['QuestionId', 'id', 'imagePath', 'thumbPath', 'rank', 'timeStamp']);
        }]);

        $data = $builder->select([
            'Id', 'uid', 'type', 'rank', 'questionText', 'totalMarks', 'negativeMark as negativeMarks', 'note', 'solutionText', 'status', 'timeStamp',
        ])->get()->toArray();
```

and i get this output

```
 [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "uid": "123456789098760",
            "type": "multiple",
            "rank": 1,
            "questionText": "2 + 2 = ?",
            "totalMarks": 5,
            "negativeMarks": 2,
            "note": null,
            "solutionText": null,
            "status": "active",
            "timeStamp": "2020-11-17 11:42:31",
            "questionOptions": [
                {
                    "QuestionId": 1,
                    "id": 1,
                    "optionText": "5",
                    "rank": 1,
                    "isAnswer": "no",
                    "timeStamp": "2020-11-17 11:42:31"
                },
                {
                    "QuestionId": 1,
                    "id": 2,
                    "optionText": "4",
                    "rank": 2,
                    "isAnswer": "yes",
                    "timeStamp": "2020-11-17 11:42:31"
                },
                {
                    "QuestionId": 1,
                    "id": 3,
                    "optionText": "four",
                    "rank": 3,
                    "isAnswer": "yes",
                    "timeStamp": "2020-11-17 11:42:31"
                },
                {
                    "QuestionId": 1,
                    "id": 4,
                    "optionText": "7",
                    "rank": 4,
                    "isAnswer": "no",
                    "timeStamp": "2020-11-17 11:42:31"
                }
            ],
            "questionImages": [
                {
                    "QuestionId": 1,
                    "id": 1,
                    "imagePath": "12345678",
                    "thumbPath": "thumbPath",
                    "rank": 10,
                    "timeStamp": "2020-11-17 11:42:31"
                },               
            ],
            "solutionImages": [
                {
                    "QuestionId": 1,
                    "id": 1,
                    "imagePath": "storage/app/solution/image/a7bBSNRkgy.jpg",
                    "thumbPath": "storage/app/solution/thumb/a7bBSNRkgy.jpg",
                    "rank": 10,
                    "timeStamp": "2020-12-04 10:32:49"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

it works perfect and there is no issue at all but when there are numbers of users fetching quiz questions it heavily impact on DB as there are so many request at a time which causes Db failure , though there is not any complex queries but when so many query are called at once it causes problem So is there any  way to get those data on single query or in better way so that I can optimize my code.
Any help would be appreciated please also if something misunderstood please ask.
Thank you !!

Comment: Looking at your code I would not assume this query is very heavy. In total this code will do 4 queries in total. 1 for `Question` and 3 for the relationships. Very optimized in my opinion. Does your application experience slow responses (long query times)? Quick tip: you can combine all `with` into a single call `with(['questionOptions' => ..., 'questionImages' => ..., ...])` Could you maybe show your migrations?

Comment: I don't use migrations instead i use custom implementation on DB and almost all the fields are there in json output .... but can this work be done in single query with the help of sub query....

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-chunk) with query builder. If you are using eloquent for large data where you need to manipulate the result then raw sql is quick than eloquent.

Comment: can you  please little elaborate how to make chunk for this query as i have to fetch all the questions related to one test  at once